# Is there a way to optimize a function with categorical arguments with scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, gis, raster

I'm building a model that makes some predictions about landcover by applying some filters to raster datasets. There are four possible filters: "less than", "greater than", "between" and "outside of". My goal is to use scikit-learn to find the combination of filters on the various rasters that results in the smallest error between the output raster and the landcover raster I'm validating against.

The problem is that to the best of my knowledge the optimization functions in scikit-learn are meant to handle functions with arguments that are floats, not integers or categoricals. A call to my objective function looks something like this:

```py
objective([2, 3, 'between', 5, 0, 'greater'], [raster1, raster2])
"""
note that the 0 is not strictly needed, but a placeholder is needed to
work with the scipy.optimize functions
"""
```

Which would mean "create a mask where each cell is true if and only if the corresponding cell is between 2 and 3 in raster 1 and greater than 5 in raster 2" (and then evaluate how good the prediction is). Scipy.optimize functions don't like categorical arguments which is fine; I can coerce the floats that scipy will use to integers and then map those to the categories. My concern is that because scipy will be providing floats, it might get stuck in a local minima. Like if 1, 2, 3, and 4 map onto "less than", "greater than", "between", "outside of", then scipy might be providing a 2.4 for the categorical argument (maps to greater than), and then when it perturbs to 2.6 and becomes "outside of", the function might perform more poorly and the optimization will stop exploring that path without ever getting to "between", which could be the optimal argument.

Is there a better way to handle these categorical arguments? Are some optimization functions less prone to the problems I mentioned? I was considering using the differential evolution algorithm since I feel like by having enough random mutation I can get over the barriers I was talking about, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: How many combinations of masks do you have? You could apply optimization on the combinations (if there aren't many). Otherwise, you could try an optimization method that does not rely on gradients, such as basin hopping, rounding the argument to the nearest integer.

Comment: There are 9 rasters, and each can have one filter (greater, less, between, outside) applied to it. What exactly do you mean by applying optimization on the combinations?

Comment: First option: something less elegant, like applying an optimization on each of the (9**4=6561 in your case) possible combinations and getting the global minimum

Comment: Check `scipy.optimize.brute`

Comment: Ah I see. There are four types of filters, but each filter also takes a float or pair of floats that determines which values will be filtered out (like filtering out values under 2.2 or outside of 4.5 and 6.8). The optimization isn't trying to find the best combination of the four filters to each raster, it's trying to find the single best filter and parameters for that filter for each raster (a logical AND is applied at the end to get the final result to be validated). So the solution space is too big to be brute forced.

Comment: Could brute force be used for the choice of filters and classical gradient method to determine optimal parameters given the filter choice? For each couple of raster, there are only 4*4 combinations of filters? Also, maybe the number of filters could be reduced: "less than" is a particular case of "between" with the lower bound very small?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure to get what the objective function is doing: is it `sum(AND( Filter(type1, bounds1, raster1), Filter(type2, bounds2, raster2))`?  i.e. counting the number of common pixels after applying a filter on each raster

Comment: The objective function does this: Applies a mask to each raster, resulting in a binary raster output. Then, the logical AND of all of those outputs is taken. For that output, 1s are trees and 0s are not trees. Then the output is compared to a validation raster. The final score is -(n_truepos+n_trueneg - n_falsepos-n_falseneg). So a perfect match is -1 and an inversion is 1.

I could probably reduce the filters like you said; that's a good idea. I'm not sure I can brute force the best filters without peturbing parameters and get good results though.